# Can I get a business profile (and so VAT-less invoices - EU) for Google Drive without using G Suite?

Tags: google-drive

We are a very small company and we use Google Drive to backup and share our files, we have a 200 GB plan. We are VAT payers and are not based in Ireland but in the EU, so we should get invoices from Google with no VAT. For that, our "profile type" should be set to "business". Is there a way to set this up? We do not want to use G Suite since we just need the Drive subscription.

I am trying to get this information from Google support but they are hopeless, do not understand my questions and just give me copy-pasted replies.

I am not sure it is legal for them to say that they offer this service only to private individuals.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you would need to sign up for G-suite, and just not use.   There does not appear to be a business option for storage only plans.